# Point to another document in Firebase Cloud

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm creating shopping cart website. There, I want to have multiple different products that users can pick and add to its cart. For database, I want to use Firebase. In the Firebase Cloud I created collection for 'products'. The problem is when I create collection for 'carts' because I don't know how to access one document from 'products.

products Model

```
export class Product {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public imgSrc: string,
        public name: string,
        public price: number,
        public category: string,
        public description: string
    ){}
}
```

cart Model

```
export class Cart{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public product: Product,
        public quantity: number
    ){}
}
```

I though I should add field for 'carts' that refers to the document path, however, when I logged it in the console, I didn't get values from that product (I get 'DocumentReference').

**Firebase Cloud**

```
carts    ----------- someid2 ---------- product: (reference) 
                                            products/someid 
                             ---------- quantity: 11 
products ----------- someid  ---------- category: ...
                             ---------- description: ... 
                             ---------- imgSrc: ... 
                             ---------- name: ...
```

myArray2: any[] = []

```
  getData2() {
    const db = this.angularFirestore.collection('cart').get().subscribe((ss) => {
      ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        this.myArray2.push(doc.data())
      })
    })
    return this.myArray2
  }
```

console (myArray2):

```
 []
   0:
      product: DocumentReference
      quantity: 11
```

I'm guessing is something similar with creating 'post' that include some 'user', but can't find proper example for this also. The project is done with using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore `DocumentReference` fields don't automatically retrieve the values from the referenced document. To get those values, you need to perform an additional API call to `get()` the referenced document.

Since the value of your `product` field is already a `DocumentReference` that is typically fairly straightforward, but it **is** a separate, additional API call that you'll need to make.